# При выборе select переход на другую страницу

Tags: jquery

Есть разметка

```
<select>
<option data-id="сылка 1">1</option>
<option data-id="сылка 2">2</option>
<option data-id="сылка 3">3</option>
<option data-id="сылка 4">4</option>
</select>
```

как при выборе определенного select перекидывала на ту ссылку которая указана в атрибуте option средствами jquery

Comment: А как сделать через тот же select(у меня их два), чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, основываясь на данных, которые я выбрал меня перекидывала на соответствующую страницу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value">
    <option value="">select:</option>
    <option value="https://www.gismeteo.ru">gismeteo</option>
    <option value="http://www.nova-wings.ru/forecast/">nova-wings</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
  window.location.href = option.data("url");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option data-url="http://www.google.com">1</option>
    <option data-url="https://www.yandex.ru">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что это глупо

Comment: @Yuri  - аргументируйте

Comment: Обращаться к выбранному `option`, потом от туда к `data-id`... это очень заморочливо для решения такой задачи. И +название *id* для *data* не несёт никакого в себе смысла, +если там указана не ссылка или *data* вообще не указан, то выйдет конфуз

Comment: Какое ваше решение данной задачи?. По поводу атрибута data-id не вижу проблем изменив на data-url

Comment: Решение такое же, как в принятом ответе, только я бы его ещё доработал чутка